# Convert a Wordpress site into static html?

Tags: html, wordpress

Could anyone please give me ideas on converting whole established wordpress site into html?

I already searched in google, and found some links:

```
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1601946
http://sumtips.com/2011/08/convert-wordpress-to-static-html-pages.html
http://mossiso.com/2007/09/10/converting-wordpress-to-static-html.html
```

Any other easy way? Please suggest?

Comment: We're not here to Google for you, have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes. Load each page in your browser and save the HTML.

Comment: @TomWalters Iam not asking u guyz to search in google , instead iam asking you whether I can use those suggested plugins mentioned in those links... i donno why the hell people kepted '-'

Comment: We expect specific questions relating to certain techniques, usually with code examples here at SO. Giving us a bunch of pages isn't constructive.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33697/create-a-static-html-site-from-wordpress

Answer (score 27):

Use a website ripper or bot to crawl and download the complete site; that will give you a mirror of the Wordpress site in plain html and images. That's basically what those plugins do.

They won't give you of course, any of the php or dynamic aspects of the site; only plain html.

One of many rippers out there: http://www.httrack.com/ Or google for more. Or use one of those plugins. It's not any easier than that, and that's easy.

Or for a command line utility, try `wget`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Sample usage: `wget -r -p -e robots=off http://www.example.com`

Then, take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development to see how standard WordPress themes are structured in terms of file hierarchy, adding scripts and style sheets, and more. Process the text files you get to remove markup from your files and isolate text content, isolate the HTML needed, and make a theme.

Comment: "off topic" or not, I found valuable info on this page!

Comment: wget command worked well Thanks mark

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer!

Answer (score -8):

The easy way to do for you is to view the source of the page and paste this in notepad, Save this page as html and you are done, remember that It wont be a wordpress page rather a simple static html page. there isn't any other way trust me.

Comment: I have many Posts and Categories.. so in this case..?

Comment: You have to copy and paste each of the pages as htmls and save them and then update the links.

Comment: in those links i found some plugins that converts wordpress to html.. can I goahead and use them..? actually aim new to this, so iam asking you guyz, but i donno some people kepted '-' anyway, what u suggest bro?

Comment: You cant use those plugins. Those plugins are pieces of php code and that is a server side language. It wont work on simple html pages.

Comment: The prob is: I have many posts, its tough for me to rigth-click , save code and paste it in html file, I will be glad if any other tool works for me..

Comment: there isn't any other tool. It is better actually to do this via standard way. You need to Install Wordpress on your server and then out it would be very easy.

Comment: there are a lot of rippers, such as  http://www.httrack.com/